# How i can fetch table posts_tags on CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, tags, posts

i have table on MySQL "posts_tags",I wanna fetch table rows in View action in my controller but i don't know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using CakePHP's [`find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find), assuming you already have your Model set up for the `posts_tags` table.

In your PostsTagsController, it should look like this:

```
<?php

class PostsTagsController extends Controller {

    public function myAction(){

        // Now you should chose which find suits you: 'all', 'list' or 'first'

        $allData = $this->PostsTag->find('all', array(
            // Here you set up all options and conditions for your data fetch
            // See the above find() reference link for these options
        ));
        //$allData = $this->PostsTag->find('list');
        //$allData = $this->PostsTag->find('first');

        // Now you should send the data to your View
        $this->set('dataInView', $allData);
        // In your view, try to print_r($dataInView) and you'll see all the records fetched

    }

}
```